# compare a text file with string and find difference in node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have a text file which has information on all Wifi connections (like ssid, mac no, strength, etc.) which were in my laptop range 2 minutes ago. And now I run the code again and get information of current wifi connections in a string. I want to compare that text file and this string and want to know the difference. Are there any new wifi connections or not?

Please can someone help me or give me piece of code for this purpose?

Comment: Do you need to compare them via JavaScript or any *diff* software will work?

Comment: What is the format of the text files? Is it a CSV? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes , i want to compare via JavaScript.

Comment: Text files's format is .txt

Answer (score 5):

As far as i understand you want to compare two text files (which is not `JavaScript`, `arrays` or `node.js` related).  You can use online tools like [Diff checker](https://www.diffchecker.com/) and [DiffNow](http://www.diffnow.com/), or if you have installed SVN for example it provides quite good *diff* tool.

However if your question is how to do it with `node.js` the [diff](https://www.npmjs.com/package/diff) npm module is looking as the easiest solution.

*Edit:*

You can [read](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback) the files using:

```
fs.readFile(filename, callback)
```

And compare their characters by:

```
JsDiff.diffChars(file1Str, file2Str, callback])
```

Comment: I want to do it using node.js. Please can you give me code of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use native `fs` library:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

var str1 = fs.readFileSync('file1', 'utf-8');
var str2 = fs.readFileSync('file2', 'utf-8');

str1 === str2
// returns true if same content
```

Comment: `'utf-8'` is by **default**. No need to pass it as argument.